# SSH: "no matching key exchange method found" when KexAlgorithm is listed as available

Tags: linux, ssh

When I try to ssh to one of my switches I get the following error:

```
$ ssh remotehost
Unable to negotiate with 1.2.3.4 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

If I list available key exchange algorithms I can see that we do have it;

```
$ ssh -Q kex
...
...
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
...
```

Specifying it manually as an option does work, as well as creating an .ssh/config entry for it, but shouldn't this be automatically picked if it's in the kex list?

```
ssh -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 user@remotehost
```

*.ssh/config*

```
Host remotehost
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 key exchange method is disabled by default in recent SSH versions. The config option is your only way to do it. Check the [openssh legacy issues page](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html) for details

Answer (score 3):

Working for me:

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -c 3des-cbc user@remotehost
```

Not working for me .ssh/config:

```
Host remotehost
  Ciphers 3des-cbc
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Answer (score 1):

**For MobaXTerm**

```
----
mkdir -p .ssh
touch .ssh/config
----
vim .ssh/config
----
Host 10.64.88.189
#Legacy changes
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
Ciphers +aes128-cbc
```